# using shutil.copytree without copystat

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to write a python script backing up a folder, and keeping it for x days.

I use

```
shutil.copytree(source, finaldest)
```

My problem is, the timestamp from the original files persists, meaning the folders will be deleted if the files within is older than x days. What i want is the timestamp to be the time of backup, regardless of the original creation date

Comment: Do you need to access the contents of the folder? You could instead create an archive that way the files are preserved, but you still get the modified time.

Comment: This is not optimal for me. The script will backup receipts (this is for a construction company, meaning there is alot of them) in case someone accidentally deletes an important one. I setup a special cloud login to access the backups, and thus would like to reproduce the original structure for ease of use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing the `copytree()`, you can then modify the timestamps on the files like so:

```
import os

for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(finaldest):
    os.utime(dirpath, None)
    for file in filenames:
        os.utime(os.path.join(dirpath, file), None)
```

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: utime() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Apparently `utime()` needs a `None` parameter to specify that it should use the current time, or you could specify your own custom time as a tuple (see the docs for more info).

Comment: Thanks for helping out! your solution works flawlessly